# Milestone rendering in Kendo Gantt chart

Tags: kendo-ui, milestone, kendo-gantt

Working with Kendo Gantt chart to show milestone in the chart. The chart shows it as a task type. The setting for milestone type task is start and end date is same. Please let me know if there is any other setting we need

Comment: Can you please clarify the expected result?

Comment: Here's an example where "Project kickoff" is a milestone: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/index

Answer (score 0):

It was a code issue. The start date and end date were saved the same. However before binding the time for the end date was changed to 23:23:59, and that's why it was not displayed as a milestone. Fixed the date and time to be the same, and the milestone started showing.